# Do I need to include any code in my javascript other than the ajax GET function in order to pass my variables to my php script and then run it?

Tags: php, jquery

This code seems to be consistent with what I've seen on various forums. I don't have any syntax errors as far as I can tell, and my javascript seems to be working correctly, but I'm not getting any emails.

```
$("#Contact").click(function(){
    if (clicked === 1 && armed === 1){
        $.ajax({
            type: GET,
            url: Scripts/contact.php,
            data: {
                Email: EmailAddress,
                Subject: EmailSubject,
                Message: EmailMessage,
            }
        });
    }
});    

<?php
$email = $_GET['Email'];
$subject = $_GET['Subject'];
$message = $_GET['Message'];
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
$headers .= 'From:' . $email . "\r\n";

mail("me@example.com", $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

I'm thinking I'm going to need a line of code in my jquery script to call my php function, but I don't have experience doing that and some things I've seen on the web make it seem like my code might work as is.

Comment: your `url` needs to be quoted -> `url: 'Scripts/contact.php'`. Also, are all your js variables defined - `clicked`, `armed`, `EmailAddress`, `EmailSubject`, `EmailMessage`? You also never check for success -> `success: function(result){ alert('email data sent'); }`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what is causing the issue here because I don't see your entire script. But I would recommend using the shorthand function from the jQuery library `$.get()`, as its a little more straightforward if you're just learning.

So, you could try:

```
$("#Contact").click(function(){
  if (clicked === 1 && armed === 1){
    $.get('Scripts/contact.php?Email='+EmailAddress+'&Subject='+EmailSubject+'&Message='+EmailMessage, function(response) {
      alert(response);
    }
  }
});  


<?php
$email = $_GET['Email'];
$subject = $_GET['Subject'];
$message = $_GET['Message'];
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
$headers .= 'From:' . $email . "\r\n";

// echo 'sent' if successfully sent, or 'not sent' otherwise
echo mail("me@example.com", $subject, $message, $headers) ? 'sent' : 'not sent';
?>
```

Also, ensure that the path is correct in your ajax statement, and that all of your variable names are defined before you reference them, and that there are no spelling errors, capitalization errors, etc. If your ajax statement works, and communicates with your PHP script, and it alerts 'not sent', then you know that the error is coming from somewhere in your mail script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the URL to the PHP script in quotes:

```
 url: 'Scripts/contact.php',
```